YOLOv8: Real-Time Object Detection with Webcam
enter image description here I have this error when i run the code that deploy my model YOLOv8 in real-time object detection with webcam
I have this error when i run the code that deploy my model YOLOv8 in real-time object detection with webcam , i need your helps please

What is your error? Please include your code and error in the question.

Have you installed it correctly? Ensure you have ran this in your command line:

pip install ultralytics

